# What will be the case in-respect to memory if any variable/object is declared inside an infinite loop?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I want to know how the following scenario behaves in respect to memory.

Furthermore

1. What will happen to the previous object after each iteration.
2. Does Garbage Collection comes into picture? If yes, then at which point ?

Let say there is a person class.

```
public class Person {
    String name;    
    public Person() {
    this.name = "foo";
    }
}
```

And we have an infinite loop in main method

```
   while(true){
        Person p = new Person();
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What will happen to the previous object after each iteration.

It will be eligible for GC, as it is no longer in scope.

> 2. Does Garbage Collection comes into picture? If yes, then at which point ?

As this is a short-lived object, very soon. There might even be optimizations in place (such as stack allocation) that don't require the GC to do any work.

Comment: So, for some-time previous objects can occupy some space?

Comment: In a normal case yes, but the JVM does tricks for short-lived objects, so the code would probably be optimized to something completely different.

Comment: @Abhishek that’s a weird question. Of course, the “previous objects” can occupy space for some time. That specific time of an object starts when you create it. From the time of the creation up to some unspecified time in the future, it may occupy space. Your notion of “previous” has no meaning to the object’s lifecycle.

Comment: @Holger I wanted to be clear whether the object created in the last iteration gets removed from memory instantly or remains when the next iteration is happening.

Comment: @Abhishek that's not something you need to care about, nor can it be accurately known.

Comment: @Abhishek an object is never “removed”. That’s a wrong mindset. An object has some state and the associated data is stored somewhere in memory. That memory might get overwritten when being used for something else. But just because the garbage collector has identified some memory as reusable, it doesn’t imply that the memory actually gets reused nor that the reuse implies immediate overwriting. Even free memory contains *something* that you will never have access to and that may be the data of objects that died long ago but haven’t been overwritten.

Comment: @Holger thanks... (correct me if I am wrong) all those objects becomes un-referenced objects and so there are no such issues as Memory Leak (OutOfMemoryError) ?
Can you please provide any good reference to read all about java-memory management?

Comment: @Abhishek basically yes, as soon as you stop using it, it is eligible for being reclaimed, but the process of reclaiming it will be driven by the memory demands.